# Do I need an ITIN to submit form W8BEN when required by the payer?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, itin

I'm an Indian citizen residing in India. I made some money doing online tutoring in a site called Student of Fortune. But if I have to withdraw the funds, I need to submit a W8BEN form. The form asks for "U.S Taxpayer Identification number (SSN or ITIN)". Since I'm not a US citizen, the only one applicable to me is the ITIN. But is this necessary for me?

I referred the IRS website, and it says, "IRS issues ITINs to foreign nationals and others who have federal tax reporting or filing requirements and do not qualify for SSNs. A non-resident alien individual not eligible for a SSN who is required to file a U.S. tax return only to claim a refund of tax under the provisions of a U.S. tax treaty needs an ITIN." How do I know if I'm required to file a U.S tax return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the instructions to the form](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw8ben/ch02.html#d0e285) - yes, you do need an ITIN.

> **Line 6**.   ....
>
> *If you do not have an SSN and are not eligible to get one, you must
>   get an individual taxpayer identification number (ITIN). To apply for
>   an ITIN, file Form W-7 with the IRS. It usually takes 4-6 weeks to get
>   an ITIN.*

Comment: Can you have a look at this page:- http://www.proz.com/forum/business_issues/232238-need_an_itin_number_for_a_w_8ben_to_work_for_a_us_agency.html The situation mentioned there is similar to mine, yet the conclusion they arrive at is that ITIN is not needed.

Comment: @JobinIdiculla I think they're quoting an IRS response to someone specific. I have no idea what your situation is and I'm not a tax adviser, so I cannot categorically say anything other than what I can find in the form instructions. Note that that opinion based on this sentence: "you will not have to enter a U.S. Federal TIN on Line 6, because this is not U.S. sourced income *and the Form W-8BEN is not required to be filed.* ". In your case the payer *does* require you to file this form. You should inquire with the payer if it is indeed required in your case. If it is - you should fill line 6.